# Reading custom datatype from FireStore using Codeable

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, codable

I am using Codable to read custom data types (map) from my Firebase Firestore. my understanding is this is a less intensive way to retrieve data.

The script itself works with just the GBplayer struct (retrieves the full list in the SwiftUI view), but when adding in the shotAverages struct, the players that have values in the Firestore document disappear from the list (and therefore aren't being retrieved).

Data Models

```
struct GBplayer: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var status: String
    var age: String
    var height: String
    var college: String
    var team: String
    var position: String
    var shootingAverages: shotAverages?
}

struct shotAverages: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
    var aveTWOperc: Double
    var aveTHREEperc: Double
    var aveFTperc: Double
    var aveeFGperc: Double
}
```

Data View Model

```
class GBplayerModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var playerList = [GBplayer]()
    
    //get reference to the db
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    func getGBplayers() {
        db.collection("GBplayers").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No Documents")
                return
            }
           
            self.playerList = documents.compactMap { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> GBplayer? in
                return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: GBplayer.self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Have been following the guide [here](https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/). Here is also a FireStore screen grab for context (will be removing the name field)

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `aveeFGperc` and `aveeFG` don't match

Comment: `aveTHREEperc` change this value on firebase to `0.0` and try it again. `NaN` is not the datatype

Comment: `DocumentID` only works for objects at the document level, `shotAverages` does not need it. Also, adding `= UUID().uuidString` is deceiving and not a good practice, if that `id` is `nil` it means you don't have a true reference to the object.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. Essentially just needed to change the struct to match the fields. I will consider dealing with Nan another way as NaN and 0.0 in my context means different things. I have also removed the UUID()s on the additional structs